# application deploy node js, amount of instance exceeded

Tags: node.js, gcloud

i have gcloud app deploy but there is error in amount limit
this is the error

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [8] Flex operation projects/soy-alchemy-285213/regions/asia-southeast2/operations/80ed8da6-58dd-4ecb-a929-5e0462a8b224 error [RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2021-01-12T16:32:36.907Z2608.fj.0: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources
```

when i go to console, there is many service name in google cloud with limit, i dont know witch one i have to increase the quota

Comment: I agree that this is confusing. App Engine flexible (!) uses Compute Engine VMs for its instances. It is highly likely that the quota that you've exhausted is Compute Engine CPU (!) quota. Check [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas/?project=soy-alchemy-285213) specifically for that region (`asia-southeast2`). You will likely see a notification that its near|exceeded quota and can submit the request for more there.

Comment: were you able to identify the quota that is causing the message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i finally using virtual machine rather app angine, deploy node js in virtual machine is simple enough
only configuration nginx is little hard